# Required DLL for calculating distance between 2 points

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qt, measurements, dll

I have been trying to find the distance between 2 points using QGIS C++ APIs in Qt.
I used the following code :

```
 QgsDistanceArea d;
 d.setEllipsoid("WGS84");     
 qDebug()<< "Qgspoint"<< d.measureLine(p1,p2) where p1 and p2 are QgsPoint.
```

when I run the application through Qt IDE this gives the correct output. but when I run the .exe file of the same application from its release folder, it gives very low value and incorrect value.
Which DLL am I  missing for calculating the distance?

Comment: Why are you convinced that this is a DLL issue? If you are getting an error, you should place that error (as text) prominently in the question.

Comment: I am not getting errors. I am getting incorrect answer for the same code when I run the .exe file from the release folder. As far as I know when I run the .exe file, then supporting libraries are DLL files.

Comment: If a DLL were ***missing*** the app would fail to run, so it's NOT a missing DLL.

Comment: my GitHub repository(https://github.com/PuneetKumar555/QGIS_MAP_OPERATIONS). I made this application. I have also added India.tiff file(raster file) on which I am doing some calculations. follow these steps: layer-> add raster layer(india.tiff)  -> geometrical measurements(line geometry) -> draw two line to find distance between them.It gives correct result(with distanceunits in distancemeters) when I run it from QT IDE. but when I run qgis_demo.exe   file  from release folder, the same code gives results in exponential(distance unit in distacnedegrees).